# Disable line of code (JavaScript/QML) if target platform is Raspberry Pi OS (arm)

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qml

I am porting a project to Raspberry Pi OS (arm). Project written in Qt/QML with some JavaScript code. I want to disable some of that code. In C++ it is very easy with preprocessor:

```
#ifdef __arm__
  // Code for RaspberryPi
#elif defined _WIN64 || defined _WIN32
  // Code for Windows
#elif defined __linux__
  // Code for Linux
#endif
```

But how I can do that in my case with Qt/QML/JS?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to `#ifdef` in QML. The closest you can do is to use a [QQmlFileSelector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlfileselector.html) to load different versions of qml files based on which platform you're running on.

You create the QQmlFileSelector in C++ code, and you can add whatever `selector` strings you want to it.

```
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlFileSelector* selector = new QQmlFileSelector(&engine);

#ifdef __arm__
selector->setExtraSelectors("rpi");
#endif
```

Then the qml files would be placed in separate folders, like this:

```
src/
|--- MyFile1.qml    <<- Used on all platforms
|--- MyFile2.qml    <<- Default version of MyFile2
|--- +rpi/
     |--- MyFile2.qml    <<- RaspberryPi version of MyFile2
```

I recommend pulling out only the pieces that are actually different into a separate file to avoid as much code duplication as possible.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to dynamically check the platform at runtime and use Javascript if statements. This can be done with the Qt QML Type and the platform object:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#platform-prop

Note that RaspeberryPi and Linux are likely to report the same platform value. In that case, you can call from QML to C++ and use a system API to get a more detailed description of the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to create a diff file, patch whatever I need, compile application and cancel patch with `-R` argument after compilation.

Comment: While that may technically work, it sounds really inconvenient to make changes/maintain code that way.